# Mocha + Chai + Sinon stub- TypeError: Cannot read property 'set' of undefined

Tags: mocha.js, chai, sinon, stub

In `nodejs` I am in an express controller that has the response object doing this as the second statement:

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
```

When I try to stub it out

```
sinon.stub(contractorController.putcontractor, 'set').resolves(true);
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property
```

I've tried many things, please help. This controller is being imported with a require statement and the controller itself is a series of exported functions (No classes). I have been able to get this to work when I create classes, but I am not certain I am supposed to be refactoring all this code into classes just so the unit tests will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In express while unit testing the `req` and `res` objects with all their related methods both need to be stubbed.

```
    const res = {
        set: sinon.stub(),
        get: sinon.stub(),
        ...
       }
```